# Brightscript : Web Accordion effect

Tags: accordion, roku, brightscript, scenegraph

Right Now I'm creating An application. Here we have Help sections. Usually, Giant applications like Youtube,NetFlix and Vimeo are not showing their Help section in their App. But In our Case, We wanted to show the Help portions. So it will have some questions. But From the design,It is the same like Accordion effect.

[image]

I know It is very hard to do it. I don't know, how to to get focus if I use simple Labels.

I have tried some different methods.

**Method 1** : By using `Label` one by one. So I can **hide** and **show** by using `visible` property.

**Doubt** : So how can I get the focus? so If there are 20 questions, How can I set focus?

**Method 2** : By using `LabelList`. So it has autofocus.

**Doubt** : So how can I **hide** and **show** contents by using LabelGroup? I think, there is no visible property.

And finally,  I used an Animation.

[Please visit this image](https://j.gifs.com/P1QE9n.gif)

For this, I have used **Vector2DFieldInterpolator** [Animation](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Vector2DFieldInterpolator)

And Here is my Code.

```
<component name = "AnimationV2DExample" extends = "Group" >
  <children>

    <Rectangle 
      width = "900" 
      height = "330" 
      color = "0x10101000" >

      <Label
      id="QuestionLabel"
      text="What is this?"/>

          <Rectangle 
          id="answer1rect"
          width = "900" 
          height = "330" 
          color = "0x10101000" >
              <Label
              id="AnswerLabel"
              text="This is a Roku App."
              visible="false"/>
        </Rectangle>
        <Label
          id="QuestionLabel1"
          text="What is that?"/>

          <Rectangle 
          id="answer2rect"
          visible = "false"
          color = "0x10101000" >
              <Label
              id="AnswerLabel"
              text="This is a Roku App."
              visible="false"/>
        </Rectangle>

        <Animation 
          id = "exampleVector2DAnimationrev" 
          duration = "7" 
          easeFunction = "outExpo" >

          <Vector2DFieldInterpolator 
            id = "exampleVector2D" 
            key = "[ 1,  0 ]" 
            keyValue = "[ [0.0,50.0],  [0.0,0.0] ]" 
            fieldToInterp = "AnswerLabel.translation" />

        </Animation>



    </Rectangle>

  </children>

</component>
```

And Here is Brightscript

```
sub init()
      examplerect = m.top.boundingRect()
      centerx = (1280 - examplerect.width) / 2
      centery = (720 - examplerect.height) / 2
      m.top.translation = [ centerx, centery ]
      m.revanimation = m.top.findNode("exampleVector2DAnimationrev")
      m.answer = m.top.findNode("AnswerLabel")
      m.answerRec = m.top.findNode("answer1rect")
      m.qustion1 = m.top.findNode("QuestionLabel1")
      m.qustion1.translation = [40,100]
      m.answer.translation = [50,50]
      m.question = m.top.findNode("QuestionLabel")
    end sub

    function onKeyEvent(key as String, press as Boolean) as Boolean
        handled = false
        if press then
            if(key = "OK" AND m.question.id = "QuestionLabel")
             m.answer.visible = true
             m.revanimation.repeat = false
             m.revanimation.control = "start"
             handled = true
            end if

        end if
       return handled
    end function
```

So How can I do a successful Accordion with this? Am I going in a right way? Or If it is not possible, Please suggest me the better way.

Comment: I've never done it but it sounds like an interesting challenge.  Did you try working with LabelLists and or MarkupLists?  From the markupList example you can make stuff happen as the focus changes; https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Lists+and+Grids+Markup

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help.Here,the description portion should hide and visible. we can hide the whole list. But how can I hide and visible if I use Labellist with contentnode. Is it possible?

Comment: I have tried with Labellist and Markuplist

Comment: Can you please join to this chat? - http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/125578/brightscript?tab=general